# How can I fix the error: No ‘prefix’ candidates produce the expected contextual result type ‘[String]’?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swiftui

I’m trying to access a variable across different files, basically between the `ContentView` and a subview.
I’ve created an `@State private var` within my `ContentView` and a `@Binding var` within my subview. 
I have a dictionary of type `[String: Int]`, and I’m trying to calculate the frequency of words in a PDF.
When I order the items in the dictionary and take the top 5 using the prefix, I want the var to be updated so I can display it in the app itself through the content view.

The error is produced at `topFive = mostFrequent.prefix(5)`. 
I think the issue is that I’m saying [String] for the type and I probably need to be doing something else but I’m not sure. To lay it out clearly, the app will sort the words of the PDF by frequency and display them within the app. I had no issues doing this with just printing the words in the console, but my issue is displaying it within the app itself.

```
struct ContentView: View { 
    @State private var documentUrl: URL?
    @State private var topFive: [String] = []
             
    var body: Some View { 
        EmptyView().sheet(item: $documentUrl { url in PDFComponent(topFive:$topFive, url: url) 
            SheetView()
        }
    }

    struct PDFComponent: UIViewRepresentable { 
        @Binding var topFive: [String]
        let documentContent = NSMutableAttributedString()
        func updateView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) { 
            enumerate(in: docSubstance.string) { 
                topFive = mostFrequent.prefix(5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mre] so we can help solve this?

Comment: I tried my best, but there’s just too many pieces that are interconnected. I hope what I’ve added helps somewhat

Comment: [mre]s are usually not the original code & removing parts, but the simplest example you can recreate of the issue. It's much easier to get answers when there is code that doesn't work as intended that we can run.

Comment: where are you getting most frequent from and what is the type? Did you forget an argument for enumerate(in:)?

Comment: This has ***nothing*** to do with neither SwiftUI nor Catalyst. Please take the time and effort to reduce your problem into a minimal/reproducible example, as was already requested.

Comment: prefix() results in an array slice, not an array. Array<String>.SubSequence is not equal to [String].

Answer (score 4):

your are getting an array of substring in your topFive, try using this to get an array of strings:

```
topFive = mostFrequent.prefix(5).map{String($0)}
```

Comment: That worked! I forgot about the result of prefix() being an array slice not an array.

Answer (score 1):

like in the previous answer is said, this is caused because the result type is an ArraySlice

Another approach

```
topFive = Array(mostFrequent.prefix(5))
```